# Next.js api not working correctly when fetching

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I made a route in app/api/hello/route.js.

I can go to the URL www.localhost:3000/api/hello?id=1 and it works. My API is getting all the images from a resources folder, and returns the image's name based on the ID.

Let's say I have a folder with 3 images (elements: 0, 1, and 2) when I make a GET request with ID 2 my api returns the name associated to the last image. If the endpoint is called with an ID out of index or without it, then it returns a error message.

```js
import fs from 'fs/promises';

export async function GET(request) {
  const folderPath = './app/resources';

  try {
    const files = await fs.readdir(folderPath);
    // Obtener el parámetro 'id' de la solicitud y convertirlo a un número entero
    const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(request.url.split('?')[1]);
    const id = parseInt(queryParams.get('id'));

    if (!isNaN(id) && id >= 0 && id < files.length) {
      // Verificar que el ID sea válido
      console.log(id)
      const fileName = files[id];
      

      return new Response(JSON.stringify({ name: fileName }), {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      });
    } else {
      return new Response(JSON.stringify({ error: 'Imagen no encontrada' }), {
        status: 404, // Not Found
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ error: 'Error al leer archivos.' }), {
      status: 500, // Internal Server Error
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    });
  }
}
```

And this, works fine. At least using the browser. But for some reason, when fetching the endpoint the result ins't the expedted.

My tree folder it's like App/Characters/[id]

So I have this component that's showed in the page.jsx of my [id] folder.

```js
import Image from 'next/image'

const fetchImages = async (id) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/hello?id=${id}`);
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('La solicitud no fue exitosa');
      }
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error al cargar la imagen:', error);
      return null;
    }
  }
  

export default async function LoadImage( {id} ) {
    console.log(id)
    const images = await fetchImages(id);
    return <h1>test</h1>
}
```

So when the id is 0 (http://localhost:3000/characters/0) it returns the picture's first name correctly.

But, for some reason when the ID is one (http://localhost:3000/characters/1) it returns:

`{ files: [ 'imagen1.png', 'imagen2.png' ] }`

What's happeing here? Notice that when I go to http://localhost:3000/api/hello?id=2 it returns
`{ name: 'imagen2.png' }` correctly. I also noticed that for some reason I can't use postman.

Thanks.